# How to combine 2 Linux PC to serve Owncloud server

Tags: cluster, owncloud

I just create owncloud server using my old PC with Intel Quadcore, 8GB memory, Centos 7, Apache, Mysql database. I already install RAID drive to make the read speed more faster. However, I try to upload all my files (about 1.8TB of Documents, Photo, Music, and Video) to this Owncloud server and as a result I already spend about a day just to upload less then 30% with the server load between 4-5. I then come up with idea I have another same PC and I plan to combine this another PC to make the process faster. I read that there are some clustering open source like Beowulf cluster. My question is can I use Beowulf cluster (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster) for Owncloud or any other clustering software that I can use? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Owncloud supports scale-out model for using multiple servers:

https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/operations/scaling_multiple_machines.html

But the primary question above is what your bottleneck is. Depending on where the vast majority of load actually happens, you can do quite a few things:

- Is it network-bound, specifically slow with uploading smaller files? To my knowledge, owncloud [sync files one-by-one](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=15046); having more than one servers won't help you with that. One thing you can do about this, is hooking your existing hard drive directly up to the server, and doing a local sync first

Lower-probability problems:

- Is it DB-bound? (check: mysql CPU usage on server) If so, you can move the mysql server to the other computer, and run it from there.
- Is it server-application-bound? (check: PHP CPU usage on server) If so, you can set up a load-balancing between the two servers, install php+owncloud on the second one, point it to the first one's DB instance, and reduce the load.

Comment: I upload using gigabit cable, So far I believe there is no problem with the data connection because I already try to copy manually from my computer to my server about 500GB it only took about 1+ hours. I re-check again the load, I think the biggest load come from httpd and mysql comes second. FYI, I also running zoneminder cctv with the same server. So, can I split the load of httpd to 2 computers?